# How to sum and subtract values using update with group by Sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update

MyTable:

```
item_name   Qty     item_area
Belts        2        India
Shoes        20       US
T-Shirt      10       India
T-Shirt      12       US
T-Shirt      25       US
```

I get this by select group by query

```
SELECT item_name, Sum(item_qty) as Qty, item_area
FROM dbo.item_stocks
group by item_area, item_name
```

and my output is below:

```
item_name   Qty     item_area
    Belts        2        India
    Shoes        20       US
    T-Shirt      10       India
    T-Shirt      37       US
```

Now i need to subtract and update .How can i do this ?
For eg. i want to subtract 5 T-Shirt ,it will update in MyTable?

> T-shirt=37-5=32

how can i update in MyTable?

Comment: can you please provide your expected output to show how your mytable will look after update

Comment: on what basis you -5 will update two rows of US??

Comment: @fa06 i have no idea but i need after sum 32

Comment: @nikhilsugandh that's for sample only i can provide any values

Comment: Why did you want to subtract?　How could you update your table?

Comment: @D-Shih some items are purchased by customer means we need to subtract from stocks right?

Comment: Which row you will update, the one with `Qty = 12` or `Qty = 25`??

Comment: any one row @Sami

Comment: What if the subtract number greater than 25? during 25 to 36

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to choose any one row to subtract.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY item_name,item_area order by Qty desc)rn 
   FROM item_stocks
)

update CTE
set Qty = Qty - 5
where rn = 1 and  item_name = 'T-Shirt' and item_area = 'US'

SELECT item_name, Sum(Qty) as Qty, item_area
FROM item_stocks
group by item_area, item_name
```

Answer (score 2):

just add a column which denotes in/Out, say INOUT

don't update row, just add new row for the stock sale.

Here,

> INOUT = 1 denotes IN and 2 denotes OUT

table structure like

```
item_name   Qty     item_area    INOUT
Belts        2        India        1
Shoes        20       US           1
T-Shirt      10       India        1
T-Shirt      12       US           1
T-Shirt      25       US           1
T-Shirt       5       US           2
```

now your query looks like that

```
SELECT item_name, 
  Sum(case when INOUT = 1 then item_qty else (0-item_qty) end) as Qty, 
  item_area
FROM dbo.item_stocks
group by item_area, item_name
```